# How to sum one or another case in MySQL?

Tags: mysql

Originally i use the SUM() function to count occurrences, and the code i use looks like this:

```
SELECT
        SUM(IF(p.FININTER = 1,1,0)) AS Internacionales,
        SUM(IF(p.FININTERNG = 1,1,0)) AS 'Internacionales NG'
```

And this works fine.

Now  i want to add the results of two different cases into one. I can't get it to work. So far i have the following:

```
SUM(IF(p.FININTER = 1,1,0)) OR SUM(IF(p.FININTERNG = 1,1,0)) AS Internacionales,
```

There are no errors but i just get 1 as a value and not the correct result of the sum. What am i missing? Any ideas?

Comment: You were OR'ing the result of two different sums.

Comment: what datatype is `FININTER` and `FININTERNG`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SUM(IF(p.FININTER = 1 or p.FININTERNG = 1,1,0)) AS Internacionales
```

or

```
SUM(p.FININTER = 1 or p.FININTERNG = 1) AS Internacionales
```

or

```
SUM(case when p.FININTER = 1 or p.FININTERNG = 1 then 1 end) AS Internacionales
```

Answer (score 1):

Mysql allows an even simpler syntax:

```
SUM(p.FININTER = 1 OR p.FININTERNG = 1)
```

In mysql, summing a boolean is the same as counting the number of times it's true, because in mysql `true` is `1` and `false` is `0`.

Using this style can make your code a lot neater.